# Is there a difference between a left and a generalized inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, generalized-inverse

The title says it all. A [generalized inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse) is a left inverse but is the converse true as well? The same should then hold for right inverse. If not, what would be an example for matrices

Comment: One quick difference between generalized inverses and left inverses is that when defining (one-sided) inverses, you require a unit element, i.e., you need at least the equation $\ell r = 1$ to hold and that requires a unit $1$. Generalized inverses do not require units to hold, i.e., you can ask for $AA^{g}A = A$ to hold without mention of a unit element anywhere.

Comment: For more examples of generalized inverses, see what are called Von Neumann regular rings. There is a nice exercise in Chapter 9, Section 3 of Hungerford's graduate Algebra text on these gadgets; see also the wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring) for a nice linear algebra illustration of Von Neumann regular rings.

Comment: @Geoff thanks for your comments. The existence of the unity is a fair point. I will check out the Von Neumann article!